# Partial template specialization of 2nd parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, specialization

I'm working on a C++11 wrapper around a C api. The C api offers a bunch of getters for various types, with a different name for each type. Values are retrieved by array of a given size, known at compilation.

I want to give the type and the array size by template, to call the right function.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct make_stop {
    constexpr static bool value = false;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : i(42) {}

    template<typename T, size_t n>
    T get();

private:
    int i = 0;
};

template<typename T, size_t n>
T Foo::get() { static_assert(make_stop<T>::value); return T(); }

template<int, size_t n>
int Foo::get() { return i + n; }

int main() {
    Foo foo;

    int i = foo.get<int, 4>();
    double f = foo.get<double, 2>();


    return 0;
}
```

But it fails to match the right function

```
main.cpp:26:5: error: no declaration matches 'int Foo::get()'

 int Foo::get() { return i + n; }
     ^~~

main.cpp:15:7: note: candidate is: 'template<class T, long unsigned int n> T Foo::get()'

     T get();
```

Comment: `template<size_t n, typename T>` or `template<typename T, size_t n>` ? I mean: you declare `template<size_t n, typename T>`, first the number and second the type, but you call (`foo.get<int, 4>()`) first the type and second the number.

Comment: Sorry, got lost in copy paste while poking at my problem, I'll edit the code

Comment: Actually, the order doesn't really matter as long as it works

Comment: I don't understand. You mean that `foo.get<int>()` , `foo.get<int, 1>()` , `foo.get<int, 4>()` should all do the same thing?

Comment: give an example of what `foo.get<int>()` and `foo.get<int, 4>()` should do and return. Your explanation and code are very confusing to me.

Comment: @bolov in a sense, yes. They will be calling the C api functions properly. What really matters is the return type

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne please clarify via an example. I see in your code that all functions return a simple data type (not an array) which contradicts your description and your first snippet. I ask for clarification. "in a sense yes" doesn't clarify anything.

Comment: @bolov I reworked the question. The function are sandboxed to simplify the example

Comment: are you actually trying to return an array? its a bit unclear what the index is for ? You have no arrays declared anywhere.

Comment: the `size_t` parameter is the size of the array

Answer (score 1):

its a bit vauge from your question, but assuming you are wanting to index into some c- arrays and return the value at `I` you can't specialize function templates like you want, but you can use some tags instead, something like..

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : is{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},ds{1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6,7.7,8.8,9.9,10.1} {}


    template <typename T> struct type_c{};
    template <size_t I> struct int_c{};

    template<typename T,size_t I>
    auto get() 
    { return get_impl(type_c<T>(),int_c<I>()); }

private:

    template <size_t I>
    auto get_impl(type_c<int>,int_c<I>) 
    { return is[I]; }

    template <size_t I>
    auto get_impl(type_c<double>,int_c<I>) 
    { return ds[I]; }


    int is[10];
    double ds[10];
};
int main() {
    Foo foo;

    int i = foo.get<int,0>();
    double d = foo.get<double,2>();
    std::cout << i << " " << d << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/kkJQrA)

Comment: Plus 1: tag dispatching is clean and moves the problem to overloads

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to `partially` specialize get for `T`. Unfortunately partial specialization for methods is not allowed by the standard. You can however get around this with a static method on a class templated by `T` and specializing the class.

Like this:

```
template <class T> struct Foo_helper;

struct Foo
{
    Foo() : i{42} {}

    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    T get()
    {
        return Foo_helper<T>::template get<N>(*this);
    }

    int i = 0;
};

template <class T> struct Foo_helper {};
// specialize Foo_helper for each type T you wish to support:

template <> struct Foo_helper<int>
{
    template <std::size_t N>
    static int get(const Foo& foo) { return foo.i + N; }
};
template <> struct Foo_helper<double>
{
    template <std::size_t N>
    static double get(const Foo& foo) { return foo.i + N; }
};


int main()
{
    Foo foo{};

    int i = foo.get<int, 4>();
    double d = foo.get<double, 2>();
}
```